# How to use shared preferences without an async method in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to show a text in a child of a container in flutter but first I have to use shared preference to get my value, i tried to use sharedprefernce in a different function but it show an error and says **Future cant be assigned to Widget**. how can i fix it?

```
 Container(
               child: _show(),
              height: 40,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 230,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

in other function i have :

```
_show() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var myVar= prefs.getInt('key');
  
  return myVar;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an `async` method inside your widget you have to use [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which just puts your app "on hold" until your data arrives.

you can use it like this:

```
 Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _show(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) { // snapshot is just the data returned from the method, to access it's data you use .data  
                if (snapshot.hasData) { // this is for null safety, since you are accessing saved data the first time you use your app you might not have anything stored, which returns null
                  return Container(Text(snapshot.data.toString())) // here I just return a simple Text widget with data
                }
                else { 
                  return Container();
                }
              }
          );,
              height: 40,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 230,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: that's so true.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, an upvote would also be appreciated :)